# Why is SELECT needed before RAISE()?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I'm learning about triggers in SQLite, and I found the syntax of RAISE() somewhat surprising, in that it needs a SELECT in order to work.

For example, this query will fail with `Error: near "RAISE": syntax error`, because I haven't added `SELECT` before RAISE().

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
    RAISE(FAIL, "Activated - mytrigger.");
END;
```

Why is `SELECT` needed before `RAISE()`. Is it just an arbitrary rule, or is there something more to it that I don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`RAISE()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) is a function like any other (e.g. `LOWER()` or `TRIM()`), not a statement and can't be executed on its own.

Comment: So this goes for every function? It must have `SELECT` before itself to work? Also, does that mean that `RAISE()` returns a result in the form of a table?

Comment: Yes this goes to any function. You need a context (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE...) in which it can be executed. From docs: *...An error code of SQLITE_CONSTRAINT is returned to the application, along with the specified error message...*